# In Visual Studio 2019 community which is the procedure to consume a wsdl?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

I've installed Visual Studio 2019, created a Console Project and I want to consume a Web Service via an existing WSDL. 
I've already followed all the guides that I've found on internet about the previous versione but none of them apply to my situation.
Can you provide me a solution to accomplish this action?
There is some additional installation component that i need to add?

Kindly,
Roberto

Comment: For a .Net framework project, you would right-click then select add/service reference. _"I've already followed all the guides that I've found on internet about the previous versione but none of them apply to my situation"_ - in what way?

Comment: I've followed what you've written and found in previous guides but when I do the right click on the project the option add service reference is not showed

Comment: The only options showed are: Add new file; Add new element; Add new folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The issue has been generated by the integration of the git repository via Visual Studio IDE which has altered the solution.
I've deleted the project, recreated it, added the service and then, via command line, I've integrated it in git.

Now it all works fine.